# Do news stories have any downside from SEO point of view?

Tags: google-news

My client releases podcasts every monday and blogs about gaming news rest of the days. He wants his blog posts to appear in Google News (and other news sites). Is there any long term downside of your blog posts being news posts?

Comment: I guess it depends on the blog. I blog about baking cookies, perhaps not- but a blog about current events, sounds good to me! Of course if your friends is doing news on the cookie marketing world, I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes @closetnoc I think it's relevant as it covers all major events in the gaming world (like E3).

Comment: Then I think it sounds like a winner! Sometimes diversity gives you the edge.

Comment: I am just a bit concerned about the long term effects. Just wondering what would happen if google decides to bury the 'old' news stories.

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't tell ya. I am thinking from augmenting the audience perspective. I do not know enough about Google handles news anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any negatives to [setting up your articles](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40787?hl=en) so they appear in Google News. Yes, you only appear in the ['news' searches](https://news.google.com/) for a certain amount of time, but obviously that's how it works, timely results – but it doesn't stop your stories appearing in the normal search results.

You can see an example [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?pws=0&hl=en&q=hreflang%20tags&spell=1&sa=X&ei=H3GaU5HcEILTkAX-pYDICA&ved=0CBsQvwUoAA&biw=1360&bih=643). I have made a search for `hreflang tags` and in position 8 is a article from searchenginejournal.com from March 2013, which I believe they have set up to appear in the news search, as they have unique digits at the end of the URL, which is a technical requirement for news stories.

I can't imagine Google would ever 'bury' news stories so they don't appear in normal search, as there would be no good reason to do this and even if a news story is old, it can still be just as relevant information today.

Comment: You know- that was what I was thinking, but I also knew that Google news changed after I used it years ago so I felt as though I could not comment accurately. One up-vote for saying what I should have. Hell- I clicked several times but it seems to be ignoring me! ;-)